# PrimeNG p-Dropdown width narrower than content

Tags: primeng-dropdowns

I'm using PrimeNG and p-dropdown to show a bunch of filtering options.    However, in trying to make things responsive, p-dropdown seems to be fixed to a min-width of content and I can't seem to override it so that it might ellipsis the content or truncate it, etc.

This is the image before making the display narrower:
[image: Normal Width]

And this is what it looks like if I resize my browser...[image: Resized Image]

If you notice, the cost center drop down sized to min content, but nothing smaller.

If I replace the dropdown with an input box: [image: Expected Behavior]

I've tried a few different CSS options to no avail.

```
[style]="{'minWidth':'20px'}"
```

I have it working fine going the other way, it sizes to correctly when going wider, just not narrow.

So what did I miss?

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe for this to work, you need to set the `autoWidth` field to be false.

For example:

```
<p-dropdown
    [options]="cities"
    [(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
    optionLabel="name"
    optionValue="code"
    autoWidth="false"
    [style]="{ minWidth: '50px', width: '50%' }">
</p-dropdown>
```

This gives me the following:

[image]

[Stackblitz for reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-splitbutton-demo-jnj7wi?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Interestingly enough, this doesn't seem to work if I'm using CSS grids versus something like bootstrap grids.

Bootstrap fine:   CSS layouts, not so much.

Comment: Yeah I'm not so much clued up on css grid as I am working with PrimeFlex, Tailwind and bootstrap. Are you using a combination of css grids and PrimeNG?

Comment: LOL, well, I'm going to use what ever works.   I am essentially updating an older version of the same application to the newer technologies.  The original was built with Angular 1.x and bootstrap.  With that in mind, I was going to use newer technology to "catch" it up.